# Setting a Label to a Preset Point

Tags: objective-c, coordinates, cgpoint

I would like to create some preset points for my Labels in Xcode 5. To set a Label's position, you use `Label.center = CGPointMake(Xpoint,YPoint) ;`.

How do I create a preset point, so there isn't a need to type the CGPointMake and the coordinates/variables.

Is there any way to just type: `Label.center = A-Variable-That-Stores-X-And-Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
CGPoint labelCenter = CGPointMake(xPoint, yPoint);
label.center = labelCenter;
```